# Pasting Excel Data to Only Matching Values

Tags: excel

I'm struggling to find an answer to my problem. My problem is that I have a column of unique identifiers (Excel File A). On a separate excel file (Excel File B) I have the same unique identifiers but some are missing or are not relevant in this file.

I need to take the data in Excel File B and match them to Excel File A. But I can't simply copy and paste because they're not in the same order and some are missing.

How do I solve this?

Comment: this is simple. if they are truly unique, use a VLookUp

Answer (score 0):

```
=Vlookup('Excel File A!A1','Excel File B!A:A',1,FALSE)
```

Vlookup

```
1. First Part = What your looking for
2. Second Part = Column you are looking in
3. Third Part = Column number to look in
4. Fourth Part = FALSE means EXACT MATCH
```

First Workbook

[image]

Second Workbook

[image]

Formula

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: Does this just match two columns side by side? This column has 63,000 rows. There's no way I can just go through 63,000 rows looking for the word false and then having to find the corresponding unique identifier and placing it in that row. Am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: You wont be looking for the word `FALSE` that is just part of the formula.  You can drag the formula all the way down. And if it finds a matching identifier, it will place it right next to the one you are searching. If it doesn't find something, `#N/A` will be shown

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow a few steps:

1. insert `=match(symbol, List looking at,0)` in the column that you
   are looking to try to filter
2. go to the data tab an select filter
3. click on the drop down and unselect #NA (and any you don't want to
   copy)
4. select all of the filtered results and copy them
5. paste them where you would
   like.